# Relacion entre dos tablas con id diferente

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando hacer una relación entre la tabla usuarios y la tabla empresas, la base de datos fue creada previamente fuera de rails, por lo que el primary key de empresas es "idempresa" y el de usuarios "idusuario", la relación: una empresa tiene muchos usuarios y un usuario le pertenece a una empresa, siendo mi modelo empresa el siguiente:

```
class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'idempresa'
  has_many :usuarios, class_name: "Empresa", foreing_key: "empresa_id"
end
```

y el modelo usuarios:

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = 'idusuario'
  belongs_to :empresa, class_name: "Usuario"

end
```

pero a la hora de correr Usuario.last.empresa en la consola de rails, debería de obtener los datos de la empresa del ultimo usuario, pero lo que obtengo es esto:

```
  Usuario Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios"  ORDER BY "usuarios"."idusuario" DESC LIMIT 1
  Usuario Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios" WHERE "usuarios"."idusuario" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["idusuario", 8]]
=> nil
```

¿Que podría faltarme? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con

```
class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'idempresa'
  has_many :usuarios
end

class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'idusuario'
  belongs_to :empresa, class_name: "Empresa", foreing_key: "empresa_id"
end
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alter, tenia un pequeño error que no me había dado cuenta y es que había escrito mal es "foreign_key". tu respuesta me ayudo a resolverlo y ordenar el codigo